# Why FullCalendar events overlays other events and day date?

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a lot muti-day events, but they overlays other events makes them invisible.
Day date also get covered by events.

Is this issue with calendar rendering or styles, any suggestions?
My expectations for this scenario that day cell should be expanded vertically to let all events to be placed one-by-one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see you solved this, but to improve the UX you should also consider using the features described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-popover

Answer (score 1):

Found a problem in my UI kit which had custom styling for FullCalendar, day frame height has been locked by custom css.

```
.fc .fc-daygrid-day-frame {
    height: 190px;
}
```